# routing to api gateway from FeignClient for jwt authorization

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, api-gateway, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am using **Spring cloud api gateway** which validates **jwt token** and then further lets any request pass through. The corresponding yml is as below.

```
    server:
  port: 9000
  
spring:  
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY

  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: EMPLOYEE-SERVICE
        uri:
          lb://EMPLOYEE-SERVICE
        predicates:
        - Path=/employee/**
        - Method=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
        filters:
        - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
        - AuthorizationHeaderFilter
        
      - id: USER-SERVICE
        uri:
          lb://USER-SERVICE
        predicates:
        - Path=/api/auth/**
        - Method=POST

      - id: RATING-SERVICE
        uri:
          lb://RATING-SERVICE
        predicates:
        - Path=/ratingsdata/**
        filters:
        - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
        - AuthorizationHeaderFilter        
        
               
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:9761/eureka
```

I am using feign client to call RATING-SERVICE from EMPLOYEE-SERVICE. Now if any request being made to RATING-SERVICE from any other microservice(e.g from EMPLOYEE-SERVICE) should also be validated with jwt token. I tried below code but it didn't work.

```
   @Autowired
    private RatingService ratingService;
Double empRating = ratingService.getRating(employee.getManagerPoints(), employee.getPeersPoints(), employee.getDepartment().getDeptName());




 @FeignClient(name = "RATING-SERVICE", url="http://localhost:9000")
public interface RatingService {

    @GetMapping("/ratingsdata/{managerInput}/{peerInput}/{dept}")
    Double getRating(@PathVariable Double managerInput, @PathVariable Double peerInput,
            @PathVariable String dept);
}
```

Comment: please let me know if you found a solution? my issue may be similar described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75577216/unable-to-conditionally-route-from-kafka-listener-to-different-endpoints-via-spr

Answer (score 0):

Although there isn't really a question here, I'll answer!
You have no code or process for routing calls back through the gateway (which is what I'm looking to do).

Once the original request has passed through the gateway to your first service (Employee-service), the second call (to rating-service) **does not** pass through the gateway; OpenFeign look-ups the service you're calling and issues the request directly, hence it is not being authorized.